# MySQL select if all distant children meet condition

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image: Reduced database schema]

I have a question regarding a (at least for me) complicated SQL statement to make. Given an `interface` I want to find all `access_lists`, which can be used on that `interface`. I'm creating a Ruby on Rails application and the working Ruby code for that task is as follows (should be pretty self-explanatory):

```
class Interface < ActiveRecord::Base

  def valid_access_lists
    # find all valid networks (.ip() converts object into manageable IP object)
    valid_networks = self.routes.map { |route| route.network.ip() }
    return AccessList.includes(access_list_elements: [{ rule: [:ip_from] }]).all().select do |acl|
      # all rule.ip_froms are in valid networks?
      acl.access_list_elements.all? do |acle|
        # current rule.ip_from is in any of the valid networks?
        valid_networks.any? { |network| network.include?(acle.rule.ip_from.ip()) }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The problem with that is, that it is (as expected) super slow (and yes, N+1 queries are prevented by the `includes`).
My approach to resolve this issue is to write an SQL statement that does everything that `valid_access_lists` does at once.

The following statement gives all the `valid_networks` as `((network_addr1, broadcast_addr1), (network_addr2, broadcast_addr2), ...)`. One problem here: It only accounts for IPv4 addresses (as can be seen in the 2nd line when the broadcast address is calculated using the logical OR). If a record in `ips` is IPv4, the `ips.ip_high IS NULL`, otherwise, both columns are `NOT NULL`. IPv6 addresses are built by performing `(ip_high << 64) + ip_low`.
The idea of calculating both, network and broadcast addresses, is to check the `ips` of the `rules` with the `BETWEEN` operator.

```
SELECT coalesce(nw_ips.`ip_high` << 64, 0) + nw_ips.`ip_low` AS nw_addr,
(coalesce(nw_ips.`ip_high` << 64, 0) + nw_ips.`ip_low`) | ((1 << (32 - nw_ips.`prefix`)) - 1) AS bc_addr FROM `ips` nw_ips
LEFT JOIN `routes` ON nw_ips.`id` = `routes`.`ip_network_id`
LEFT JOIN `interfaces` ON `routes`.`interface_id` = `interfaces`.`id`
WHERE `interfaces`.`id` = 1
```

This statement joins tables to enable checking of `rules` based on `access_lists`

```
SELECT `access_lists`.* FROM `access_lists`
LEFT JOIN `access_list_elements` ON `access_lists`.`id` = `access_list_elements`.`access_list_id`
LEFT JOIN `rules` ON `access_list_elements`.`rule_id` = `rules`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `ips` ON `rules`.`ip_from_id` = `ips`.`id`
WHERE ...
```

The main problem here is, that I need to group the `rules` (and their respective `ips`) per `access_list` in order to check if all `rules` in an `access_list` are included in at least one `valid_network` and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: How attached are you to MySQL? I would go Postgres all the way here for the native [IP data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-net-types.html) (and for consistency).

Comment: Sadly I cannot switch to a different DBMS. The most I can do is switch to a single column format (f.e. VARBINARY(16)), but I'd prefer not to, since that requires a lot of refactoring. Also, I suppose checking the address format IPv4/IPv6 becomes harder then.